# Python: Error while pushing sensor data with raspberry pi to xively TypeError: __init__()

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, temperature, xively

i try to read data with a raspberry pi from my ds18b20 temperature sensor and push them to xively.

Execution of some prerequisites and the python file in the console:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio && sudo modprobe w1_therm
source .envs/venv/bin/activate
FEED_ID=244127069 API_KEY=Nqeje SENSOR_ID=28-00000539324e python xively_ds18b20.py
```

After this, there's the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xively_ds18b20.py", line 59, in <module>
    run()
  File "xively_ds18b20.py", line 42, in run
    feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
  File "/home/pi/xively_tutorial/.envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xively/managers.py", line 266, in get
    feed = self._coerce_feed(data)
  File "/home/pi/xively_tutorial/.envs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xively/managers.py", line 289, in _coerce_feed
    feed = Feed(**feed_data)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'
```

How can i solve this error? It's funny, but on another Raspberry Pi it is working...

Here's my code (xively_ds18b20.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import xively
import subprocess
import time
import datetime
import requests


FEED_ID = os.environ["FEED_ID"]
API_KEY = os.environ["API_KEY"]
SENSOR_ID_PRE = os.environ["SENSOR_ID"]
SENSOR_ID = SENSOR_ID_PRE[-7:]

# initialize api client
api = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY)

# function to read the temperature from ds18b20 temperature sensor on i2c 
def read_temperature():
   tempfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/"+SENSOR_ID_PRE+"/w1_slave")
   thetext = tempfile.read()
   tempfile.close()
   tempdata = thetext.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
   temperature = float(tempdata[2:])
   temperature = temperature / 1000
   return temperature

# function to return a datastream object. This either creates a new datastream,
# or returns an existing one
def get_datastream(feed):
  try:
    datastream = feed.datastreams.get("PiTemperature"+SENSOR_ID)
    return datastream
  except:
    datastream = feed.datastreams.create("PiTemperature"+SENSOR_ID, tags="temperature")
    return datastream

# main program entry point - runs continuously updating our datastream with the
# latest temperature reading
def run():
  feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)

  datastream = get_datastream(feed)
  datastream.max_value = None
  datastream.min_value = None

  while True:
    degreesCelcius = read_temperature()
    datastream.current_value = degreesCelcius
    datastream.at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    try:
      datastream.update()
    except requests.HTTPError as e:
      print "HTTPError({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror)

    time.sleep(10)

run()
```

Comment: Will you please provide code which is not working?

Comment: Hi, code is in the file xively_ds18b20.py, which i have posted in my question.

Comment: well, it looks like your feed 244127069 has an email in it that the Feed object is not expecting... can you inspect your feed and let us know what's in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/xively/xively-python/issues/28), you can work around this by removing your email address from the feed metadata:

> When I removed my e-mail address from the Feed Metadata (through the
>   workbench) and re-ran `api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)` it worked just fine.

However, when I look at the [latest source code on github](https://github.com/xively/xively-python/blob/master/xively/models.py#L41), I can see that `email` *is* supported:

```
class Feed(Base):
    """Xively Feed, which can contain a number of Datastreams.
    :param title: A descriptive name for the feed
    :param description: A longer text description of the feed
    :param website: The URL of a website which is relevant to this feed e.g.
    home page
    :param email: A public contact email address for the provider of this feed
    :param tags: Tagged metadata about the environment (characters ' " and
    commas will be stripped out)
    :param location: :class:`.Location` object for this feed
    :param private: Whether the environment is private or not.
    :type private: bool
    Usage::
    >>> import xively
    >>> xively.Feed(title="Xively Office environment")
    <xively.Feed(None)>
    """
    VERSION = "1.0.0"
    # Set id and feed directly as they aren't part of state. By setting them on
    # the class they won't get entered into _data and will be set on the
    # instance itself.
    id = None
    feed = None
    _datastreams_manager = None
    def __init__(self, title, description=None, website=None, email=None,
    tags=None, location=None, private=None, datastreams=None):
```

[It seems this bug was only fixed recently (June 27th)](https://github.com/xively/xively-python/commit/c463ec5fdcd4e7b70f6178fc0277f19031198b49). Can you try pulling down the latest version of `xively-python` from github, and use that instead of the current version you have?

Comment: I have used `pip install xively-python --upgrade` to install the latest version...but it says: `Requirement already up-to-date: xively-python in ./.envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=1.1.0 in ./.envs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from xively-python)
Cleaning up...` . After that, i receive the same error as before

Comment: @mcknight I don't think a new version that includes this change has been officially released yet. You'll either need to manually apply the patch, or use git to pull down the latest code and install from source.

Comment: @mcknight Installing from git is as simple as `git clone https://github.com/xively/xively-python.git ; cd xively-python ; sudo python setup.py install`. You should probably uninstall the version of xively you already have first, though.